# ESP 32 TCP connection closed by peer

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, esp32

I'm working on a project based on tracking movements using 3 ESP32 boards that sniff PROBE packets. This function is called for each ESP in a sequential way. So first I connect with all the ESPs, then this function is called and starts reading from the connection the number of packets and then each packet. The problem is that when I try to send a list of 200 packets from each ESP the server receives correctly the number of packets of the first ESP but then starts reading the packets and receives only a fraction of them (receives correctl about 140 of the 200 total and then a part of the packet 141) and then crashes. The boards are able to send all the packets but then don't receive any ACK from the server since it crashed. I can't understand why the server keeps crashing when testing with a high number of packets while it works perfectly with a single board and a low number of packets

```
int recvPseq(SOCKET s) {

  uint32_t numP;
  unsigned char netP[4];
  int res;

  res = recv(s, (char *)netP, 4, 0);
  if (res > 0) {
    if (res != 4) {
      cout << "Number of packet not entirely received! Only: " << res << " bytes" << endl;
      return 0;
    }
  }
  else if (res == 0) {
    cout << "Socket closed by the client" << endl;
    return 0;
  }
  else {
    cout << "Error while receving the number of packets: " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
    return 0;
  }

  /* NumP contains the number of packets */
  numP = ntohl(*(uint32_t*)netP);
  cout << "Number of packets: " << numP << endl;

  /* Reading the packets */
  for (int i = 0; i < numP; i++) {

    unsigned char recvbuffer[55];

    res = recv(s, (char *)recvbuffer, 55, 0);
    if (res > 0) {
      if (res != 55) {
        cout << "Packet " << i + 1 << " not entirely received! Only: " << res << " bytes" << endl;
        return 0;
      }
    }
    else if (res == 0) {
      cout << "Socket closed by the client" << endl;
      return 0;
    }
    else {
      cout << "Error while receving the number of packets: " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
      return 0;
    }

    cout << "Received " << i + 1 << endl;
  }
  return 1;
}
```

Comment: The code you show doesn't seem to be sending any "ACK"? Can you please try to create an [mcve] to show us?

Comment: This is just the inner function, I didn't want to post the entire code. It doesn't send any ack because the server should send the ack after receving all the packets, so after exiting this small function. I tried making server to sleep just before the loop that reads to check if ther was a problem in the receiving or sending buffer but I was able to send the whloe packets, so I don0't think the problem is the size of the buffers

Answer (score 0):

You do not read properly from the TCP sockets. Calling `recv(buflen=X)` may return 0..X bytes. `recv()` will not wait until the whole buffer is filled with data.

Typically `recv()`has to be called in a loop until enough data has been received. Every TCP receiver (server or client) has to do this. There is no way around this. This is just how TCP works. TCP is always byte oriented. There are no packet boundaries. You will observe all kinds of artifacts of the network infrastructure and buffers used along the path when looking at the actually received number of bytes per `recv()` call.